# How to click a link by text in Selenium web driver java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have many links in my page.One with text "Add policyhoder" ,one with text " Add" only and another "Add PP". I need to click link by text  .I am using below code to click link having text as "Add" only but it is clicking very first link having "Add" in its text i.e. ""Add PP" available on screen.Please can u help

```
Driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add"));
```

**My requirement is to click a link with exact text match . for example "Add" here**

```
<td width="100%" colspan="7">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" valign="bottom">
<input id="hidPoClaim" type="hidden" onblur="ResetScript(this);" onfocus="HighlightScript(this);" value=" PolicySummary " callfunction="" size="" name="/Root/ACORD/InsuranceSvcRs/com.c_HomePolicyInquiryRs/co.cc_AvailableFunctions[com._FunctionName='PoSummary' and com.csc_FunctionName[@Action='ShowPolicyClaims']]">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="25%" valign="bottom" colspan="1">
<strong>
<font class="flabel">Policy Claims History:</font>
</strong>
</td>
<td width="20%" valign="bottom" colspan="1">
<font class="flabel">  </font>
<a class="fLabel" onclick="INFCaptureControlID(this); DoLink('POLICYLOSS','','ADD' );return false; " onblur="ResetScript(this);return true;" onfocus="HighlightScript(this);" delimiter="|" screenaction="ADD" href="" screen="Y" objecttype="POLICYLOSS" type="Link" context="Screen">**Add**</a>
</td>
<td width="20%" valign="bottom" colspan="1">
<td align="Center" width="15%" valign="bottom" colspan="1">
<td width="20%" colspan="1">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table
```

Thanks
Dev

Comment: you are on right track , your way is fine to find element. just need to see if link is opening in same tab or new tab?

Comment: Opening in same tab. driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Add']")); is also clicking very first link having "Add" in its text

Comment: yes so my answer will work for you , please see my given answer.

Comment: No i dont have to click any  link before "Add" link. I just have to click one link having exact text as "Add"

Comment: then it should work :`Driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add"));` , can you please share website url? where you are trying?

Comment: I think you are confusing with LinkText and PartialLinkText. LinkText will find exact match with link or multiple links and PartialLinkText found link have contains  ADD text.

Comment: @HelpingHands application is not available for outside world

Comment: @DevkantKrishnatrey - is that add button is under popup?? or in normal page?

Comment: @Sagar007 I was also thinking that linkText does check exact match. But for example if I have two links "Add here" and "Add" . If i use Findlement(by.LnikText("Add"). it will clck on "Add here" if it is available before "Add" link on the page.

Comment: @HelpingHands Its a normal page. Not sure whats wrong with this code :(

Comment: what error you are getting when tying to click on Add?

Comment: It is clicking on another link(the link which strats with Add e.g. "Add here" )before this

Comment: See here : http://www.toolsqa.com/automation-practice-form/ , when i do  `driver.findElement(By.linkText("Link Test")).click();` , it click on only Link Test hyperlink , not clicking on another so it is for exact match and working for here. in your case also "Add" should work.

Comment: Please provide HTML code of "Add here"

Answer (score 3):

If it the there are 2 elements with the word "Add", Then try something like this:

```java
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Add"));
list.get(1).click();
```

To find the element by searching for the exact text, then using xpath will be more helpful.

```java
// For "Add" link, according to the HTML you've added to the question
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='**Add**']")).click();
```

Comment: What if there are multiple links with texts Add,Add JP,Add VP etc. is there any way to click a link with exact text match?.

Comment: @DevkantKrishnatrey - Then try using xpath `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Add']"));`

Comment: you need list element only if you have multiple links with specific text "Add". if you have text like "Add JP" then you can manage with single findelement as you did.

Comment: @DevkantKrishnatrey - I've update my answer. Let me know if you still face an issue.

Comment: @DevkantKrishnatrey - Check the HTML code: `... context="Screen">**Add**</a> ...` The text is `**Add**` and not just `Add`. You have to modify the xpath to exact value you want it to find. Try `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='**Add**']")).click`

Comment: Sorry that is my misatake.pasted *** in html code :( .Anyway i am using above code as suggested It is still clicking very first one "Add....." not required "Add" link so its not searching for the exact text,

Comment: @DevkantKrishnatrey - If it is possible, can you show me the complete HTML? Use gist.github.com to share your code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume because when you click on first link it opens that link page in same tab and can not find second link element as page changed , so you have to open that link page in new tab in.

I think your code would be :

```
String Newtab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN); 
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add policyhoder")).sendKeys(Newtab);

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add")).click();
```

Now above code will work for you.

Answer (score -1):

you can try using

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Add']"));
```

This would match exact text for you

Comment: i am using above code as suggested It is still clicking very first one "Add....." not required "Add" link so its not searching for the exact text,