# Java selenium how to open a link from google search results?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web, automation

I am new to automation testing in Selenium and i am doing some basic automation testing such as searching for something in Google and then clicking on a link which is required from the search results.

The code below, which i have produced works up until i get to the testing method. I am unable to select a link from the Google search page but i am not being shown any errors on my console. So i setup a thread on this particular line and it mentioned it could find the link name however the link name is used in the html code as i have checked on Google inspect.

Am i missing something obvious? I am relatively new to Selenium so any help is appreciated. Also i have tried mirroring some code from this users response *"[How to click a link by text in Selenium web driver java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33559296/how-to-click-a-link-by-text-in-selenium-web-driver-java)"* but no luck!

Thanks

```java
    package com.demo.testcases;






import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;





public class MyFirstTestScript {

private static WebDriver driver;


public static void main (String[] args)  {

    SetUp();
    testing();



}

// TODO Auto-generated method stub


@setup

    public static void SetUp () {

    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "usr/local/bin/geckodriver");
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("BBC" + Keys.ENTER);
}   
@Test
        public static void testing()  {

    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("BBC - Home")).click();


}
}
```

Comment: It's another approach, but you could build the search request into the URL that you pass to driver.get.

Comment: try using By.linkText as opposed to PartialLinkText

Comment: @camel-man I tried this approach initially but it did not work

Answer (score 2):

Once you obtain the search results for the text **BBC** on *Google Home Page* next to `click()` on the link containing the text **BBC - Home** you can use the following code block :

```
List <WebElement> my_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='rso']//div[@class='rc']/h3[@class='r']/a"));
for (WebElement item:my_list)
{
    if(item.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("BBC - Home"))
    item.click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, did you test this code? Iv just tried this now but no luck! I used this "<WebEelement>" method before however instead of using the x.path method i used the By.linktext method but it did not execute. I have now tried the code above but no still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
public class MyFirstTestScript {

private static WebDriver driver;
private static WebDriverWait wait;

public static void main (String[] args)  {

    SetUp();
    testing();
}

@setup
public static void SetUp () {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "usr/local/bin/geckodriver");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,50); 
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("http://www.google.co.uk");
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("q")));
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("BBC" + Keys.ENTER);
} 


@Test
public static void testing(){
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.linkText("BBC - Homepage"))));
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("BBC - Homepage")).click();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have just tried this code but its still not working. Did you test this code by any chance?

Comment: Its working up until the point of the search results however it does not click on the link specified. From the console i am getting this error " Exception in thread "main " org.openga.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: BBC - Home"

Comment: I tried searching for Google instead of BBC and i got the same error, it could not find the element "Google"?

Comment: Is BBC- home  first link that been popped up after getting the result ?

Comment: May be your script need to scroll down the search page

Comment: Yes it does. Ah, ill try the scroll down option it may work

Comment: If you need help with scroll down , please let me know

Comment: I am using JavascriptExecutor to scroll down but no response when i test it. This is the code i have used                          JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("scroll(0,250);");

Comment: This  is the reponse i am getting on the console:                
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 59.0.2, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 9024, moz:profile: /var/folders/xm/hzx2rrgx2kb..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, platformVersion: 15.6.0, rotatable: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}}

Comment: Yes it's correct ! Is it scrolling now ? or same issue you are facing ?

Comment: its not scrolling at all :/

Comment: after hiting the enter from your script , you should use JavaScriptExecutor for scrolling.

Comment: Iv just done some debugging as the code is similar to yours so in theory should work on my system but i am placed with this error CFMessagePort: bootstrap_register(): failed 1100 (0x44c) 'Permission denied', port = 0xa057, name = 'com.apple.tsm.portname'
See /usr/include/servers/bootstrap_defs.h for the error codes.

Comment: So finally got it to work not on the firefox browser though. I think i have some version issues with firefox but on chrome it works fine though. Thankyou :)

Comment: You can mark this answer as accepted , if it has helped you to resolve your problem. Thank you !